# Java's "forEach" to Scala

Tags: java, scala, foreach

How can the following be converted to scala? If I live it as it is, I'm getting a big type mismatch expected

```
.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {..})
```

I tried specifying entry to java.util.Map.Entry, or changing to scala foreach, doesn't work.

Let me know if you need any more info/code, and I'll create some dummy example since I'm not allowed to post the exact code.

Comment: I'd say you want an implicit conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481204/smooth-way-of-using-functiona-r-java-interface-from-scala

Comment: `for(entry <- entrySet){...}`

Comment: If it's a `java.util.Map` then you either want the implicit conversion for the function as suggested by @MarkoTopolnik, or to convert it to a scala map using `.asScala` with `import scala.util.JavaConverters._` at the top. Or you can explicitly instantiate a `new Function(){}` the way you would in Java. If it's a `scala.collection.Map` then the `for(entry ← ...)` approach is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

[Iterating over Java collections in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala)

for each in scala

```
for(entry<-entrySet){
//
}
```

or

```
entrySet.foreach{entry=>
//
}
```

or

```
.entrySet.map{entry => 
//
}
```

Comment: You should use `foreach`, not `map`. `map` may be lazy depending on the data type of `entrySet`.

Comment: `for (entry<-entrySet)` is more a equivalent of `for (entry : entrySet())` in Java.

Comment: @K-RAD yeah it works on scala collections you have to convert it to scala collections

Comment: foreach worked nicely with import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

for an implicit conversion to scala collections.

Comment: Please don't suggest using implicit conversions. [Decorators](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.convert.DecorateAsScala) are the way to go: `import scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._; javaCollection.asScala.foreach(x => doSomething(x))`.

Comment: Good point!
It's explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala

Comment: Both `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and `scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala` are deprecated. The current way is (until it is also deprecated in some future)  `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._; javaCollection.asScala.foreach(x => doSomething(x))`